# Finite Fields of orders which are four consecutive integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

As I was preparing properties of Finite Fields I realised that there are Finite Fields of orders 2,3,4 and 5 which happen to be four consecutive integers. I am just curious to know if there are four other consecutive integers which are orders of Finite Fields! Any thoughts on this please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You found the only solution.

Two of those four consecutive integers are even. If they are cardinalities of a finite field, they must both be powers of two. But they differ from each by two, and $2$ and $4$ are the only powers of two satisfying that condition.

---

Actually it is difficult to find even three consecutive integers that would be prime powers. By the above argument, the one in the middle has to be even, and hence a power of two. This implies that one of the odd neighbors is divisible by three, hence a power of three. By Catalan's conjecture (now Mihailescu's theorem) the only adjacent powers of $2$ and $3$ are $8=2^3$ and $9=3^2$.

Therefore, in addition to the four you found, the only other triple is $7,8,9$.

Comment: Invoking Catalan/Mihailescu is probably overkill for the purposes of excluding solutions to $2^a=3^b\pm1$.

Comment: Thank you for the update on three consecutive integers. The solution for two consecutive integers is infinite. Am I correct?

Comment: @LawrenceMano A good question! I think that is unknown. One number is even, so the other is $2^m\pm1$. Again, if $m>3$ Catalan/Mihailescu says that the other cannot be a proper prime power, so it has to be a prime. $2^m+1$ can be a prime only when $m=2^n$ is a power of two. $n=0,1,2,3,4$ work but no others are known. $2^m-1$ can be a prime only if $m$ is a prime. Look up Mersenne primes. Many are known, but we don't know if there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $2^p-1$ is a prime.

Comment: All, please join me in upvoting Leoli1's answer. They beat me to it by one second. At that time I only had the text up to the horizontal line.

Comment: Why can't the two consecutive integers be of the form $5^m$ and $5^m\pm1$? Can we not have any prime power plus or minus one?

Comment: Ok. Got the point. Since 5^m is odd $5^m\pm1$ has to be even and hence cannot be a prime.

Comment: great answer about two consecutive integers!

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The order of finite fields are prime powers and there are no four consecutive prime powers greater that $2$ since two of them would have to be even.